# Email notifier not working in groups in teamcity

Tags: email, notifications, teamcity

I have created a group with few users and want to send email notifications on failure of a particular project to all users of that group.

[image]

It is still showing Do not notify and Emails are not sent on failure of project. Can you please guide what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're on a half of the way to it.

Go to *Administration => Groups=>Your Group => Email Notifier*

Then select the project/projects you want to watch and mark the neccessary conditions
You should select the notification rules. the first one is what you need!
[image: Example]